# __LINE__ evaluated inconsistenly in lambda that's passed to a function-like macro

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code:

```
1.  #include <iostream>
2.  #define CALL_FUNC(f) f();
3.
4.  int main()
5.  {
6.    CALL_FUNC([](){
7.      std::cout << "I'm on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;
8.    });
9.    return 0;
10. }
```

When I compile this in Visual Studio 2012 and g++ 4.7.3, I get the output "I'm on line 8".

When I compile this in clang, I get the output "I'm on line 7", which is what I expected.

Does anyone know which of these is the correct behavior? Is there a way to get the desired behavior in VS and g++ while still having a CALL_FUNC macro?

Comment: ideone (g++ 4.7.2 shows line 9 ... http://ideone.com/afoTTj ; but that could just be some editor mismatch there

Comment: @Asaf You added a newline between `#include` and `#define`.

Comment: I just wanted to see if you paid attention... Yes...

Answer (score 4):

The standard does not specify the interaction between macro expansion and the `__LINE__` predefined macro.  In particular a macro invocation that spans multiple lines and contains a `__LINE__` token exhibits different behaviours on different preprocessors.  When part of a macro argument that is expanded, some will give it the line number of the enclosing macro head name (6), some the closing parenthesis (8) and some the `__LINE__` token line (7).  It depends on the algorithm used, and there are several that are valid and standard-conformant.

This can be demonstrated as follows:

```
#define F(x) x
F(
__LINE__
)
```

Some preprocessors will output 2, some 3 and some 4.

Comment: I'll go one step beyond what you said: I think the standard even allows (by not prohibiting it), after `#define LINE __LINE__`, for `LINE` to always expand to the same number, no matter where it appears, by claiming that when `LINE` is being expanded, the current source line becomes that of the macro definition.

Comment: @hvd: No, the standard specifies that macros are expanded at point of use, not point of definition - so it is clear that `__LINE__` expands to the presumed line number at point of use.  It is the concept of "presumed line number" that is not clear as it applies to multi-line macro invocations, and where the variations arise.

Comment: The standard says `__LINE__` expands to "the presumed line number (within the current source file) *of the current source line*" (emphasis mine) but without specifying *at all* which source line counts as "current". You're right that `__LINE__` does not get expanded in my example at macro definition time, but I did not claim it did. An implementation could say "Okay, now on line 5, I see `LINE`. I'm going to expand this. The definition is on line 1, so the current source line is line 1 until the expansion has completed."

Comment: @hvd: No, it's pretty clear that the current source line is line 5 in your example.  This is uncontroversial, and there are no preprocessors that implement that case any differently.  The problem is when an invocation spans multiple lines and "sub-invocations" are taking place "inside" it.

Comment: There are no preprocessors that implement that case any differently because it wouldn't be useful, and "real world" implementations do what makes sense. All I'm saying is that the standard fails to actually require that.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test seems to show that if you move the `});` up a line it works:

```
std::cout << "I'm on line " << __LINE__ << std::endl;});
```

gcc and msvc seem to think it is on the next line because of the `});` on the next line.
(Also, you have an extra semi-colon BTW).

Comment: But why does the inconsistency occur at all?

Comment: Because GCC (and I assume MSVC) only track line numbers for statements and full expressions, not sub-expressions, and the end of the macro is on line 8. Clang tracks sub-expressions

Comment: I think that just works because the __LINE__ is at the line where the macro invocation ends. Having several lines with __LINE__ statements in the lambda will have them all evaluate to the last line of the invocation.

Comment: @JoakimKarlsson: Yes, you are right about that. I don't think there is a workaround for that though.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Does GCC really track statements and full expressions during preprocessing, or are you talking about line numbers in warnings and error messages, rather than of the expansion of `__LINE__`?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It is the preprocessor (translation phase 4) that expands `__LINE__` macros, and at that point there are no expressions or statements yet.  Are you sure you are not confused?

Comment: Yes, you're both right, I was thinking of clang's ["point diagnostics"](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html), which are far more accurate than GCC's location tracking (e.g. errors in constructor init lists always point to the end of the list with GCC), but that's not what's happening here, because as you say this depends on the preprocessor